# Dark overlay shows after closing Fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have the following set up on my website for each of my portfolio items: http://jsfiddle.net/WQpLd/

(I couldn't get Fancybox to work in the example link above.)

A live version can be viewed on my website [here](http://crackpixels.com/).

The problem is that when I hover over the boxes and click on the 'view screenshot' link, the screenshot gets shown via Fancybox — which is fine, but when I close the screenshot, sometimes the boxes get left with a dark overlay. Only when I hover over the 'overlayed' box with my mouse will the box get back to 'normal'.

To further illustrate this, I've shot a quick video [here](http://crackpixels.com/weird/cpix.htm).

How can I fix this to make the dark overlay not appear at all after I've closed the Fancybox screenshot?

Comment: I don't experience this behavior on your site in FF5 or Chrome. As soon as the fancybox overlay appears, the image overlay disappears, although Chrome took slightly longer to remove it than FF5. Did you fix it?

Comment: No, it hasn't been fixed. Just to be clear, this behavior happens *after* the fancybox overlay has been closed. Also, it happens most of the time, not all of the time.

Comment: @J82 -- here is a version of ur fiddle with fancybox working: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/USTVR/

Comment: I've edited the question to include video to illustrate exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.

Use the latest jquery library from Google, e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>.
```

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to use the `onClosed` option to define a callback and makes the overlay disappear once more just to be safe. The mouseout callback (2nd parameter) of your `jQuery.hover()` call could separated out into a separate function so you don't repeat your code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using fancybox 2.1.0 and jquery 1.6.2, while loading a gallery dynamically.

I removed the fade out effect for closing, and it fixed it. The code I used is:

```
$.fancybox.open(images, {
  closeEffect: 'none'
});
```